# Import new branches from a different git folder on Windows only

Tags: git

This is my scenario: Alice and Bob want to work together using Git. They both have Windows PCs with (Git and) TortoiseGit installed. Alice creates a repository. She commits some changes. Then she gives a copy of her working directory on a USB drive to Bob. He creates two branches with some commits each and gives the USB stick back to Alice. Meanwhile Alice has continued to commit to her repository. Now Alice wants to **introduce the new branches into her repository**, compare them using *diff* and, if she aggrees to the changes, merge them.

How can she do this. It seems to me that this is exactly what Git is for, but I don’t get it to work. This is what I’ve tried:

[image: TortoiseGit fetch from B]

But it only tries to update the current master.

[image: TortoiseGit result window]

What it should do is get the both new branches. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do a "fetch" from the other repo.  What you want to do is add "D:\test\B" as a new remote.

```
git remote add tempRepo D:\test\B
```

This will add another remote just like your current origin.  Then you can fetch all the branches from that remote with the command

```
git fetch tempRepo
```

From that point you'd review the branch you want then pull it in with something like

```
git pull tempRepo {branchname}
```

Comment: This is obviously command line.  I'm not familiar with the tortoiseGit UI.  I'd take a look at that "Manage Remotes"  link in your first screenshot though if you're wanting to go UI.

Comment: Just go to Settings and add the remote there. It works. Thanks.